# Two buttons next to each other HTML CSS BOOTSTRAP

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am having a problem with my design.

I have two buttons on my product page. However because one is in a form, they are on top of each other(see image ).

[image: buttons]

I want to get the two buttons next to each other. Can someone help me out, please ? Below I added my HTML and CSS code.

Thanks in advance!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<div class="container text-center">
            <div class="sale">
                <h1>On Sale</h1>
                <p class="text-secondary">
                    We have new sales promotions online for a short period of time every day. We offer products from
                    popular labels and luxury brands in the lifestyle segment up to 75% cheaper than the
                    recommended retail price.
                </p>
            </div>
</div>

        <section class="on-sale">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                <?php
                    for($i = 0; $i < $countProductItems && $i < 4; $i++){
                        ?>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="product-top">
                        <a href="products/product-page.php?product=<?php echo ($saleProducts[$i]['strProductNaam']); ?>" onclick="POST"><img src="<?php echo ($saleProducts[$i]['imgProduct1']);?>" class="img-fluid" alt="Product1"/></a>
                            <div class="overlay-right text-center">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" title="Quick Shop">
                                <a href="products/product-page.php?product=<?php echo ($saleProducts[$i]['strProductNaam']); ?>" onclick="POST"><i class="fa fa-eye text-white"></i></a>
                                </button>
                                <form action="includes/shopping-cart.inc.php?action=add&id=<?php echo ($saleProducts[$i]['ID'])?>" method="post">
                                    <input class="text-center" type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1"/>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="index-page" value="index">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="product-name" value="<?php echo ($saleProducts[$i]['strProductNaam']); ?>">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="product-price" value="<?php echo ($saleProducts[$i]['strSalePrijs']); ?>">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary " title="Add to cart" name="add_to_cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="product-bottom text-center">
                        <p>
                                <?php rating_star(($saleProducts[$i]['RatingStar'])) ?>
                            </p>
                            <p><h3><?php echo ($saleProducts[$i]['strProductNaam']); ?></h3></p>
                            <?php sale_product(($saleProducts[$i]['intPrijs']), ($saleProducts[$i]['strSalePrijs']))?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    }
                ?>

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.container .sale{
    padding: 3rem 0;
    }

    .container .sale{
        font-family: var(--gugi);
    }

    .container .sale{
        padding: 0.5% 25%;
        font-size: 0.9em;
    }

.on-sale{
    margin: 50px 0;
}

.on-sale img{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    transition: 1s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.on-sale img:hover{
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.product-top{
    width:100%;
    display: inline-block;

}

.product-bottom .fa{
    color: orange;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.product-bottom h3{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.product-bottom h5{
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.make_red {
        color: red;
}
```

// codefilling text[error] - nfnjsnfjsfnbjkdsnfdsfndjsfbjabsdjhbgdgabadsg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `flex` to do it easily.

```
<div class="overlay-right d-flex justify-content-center">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"></button>
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">
          <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
        </button>
     </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You are amazing!!! I already spended 1.5hour trying to fix this. Thanks a lot. It was really simple after all :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a rule like...

```
form {
    display: inline;
}
```

...though it'd be better to give your form a class and add the rule to that class.

That said, why are you using an anchor tag inside a button? You might want to use just the anchor and style it as a button.

Finally, for a future reference, you might want to post a trimmed down version of the code as a code snippet, containing just the relevant parts. I'll add here one for the solution just as an example. It makes it so much easier for us to understand the problem.

```css
.inline-form {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<button>Left Button</button>
<form class='inline-form'>
  <button>Right Buton</button>
</form>
```

Comment: With Bootstrap you could just give the form the class .d-inline, which is just the same.